# window.location.href を 無効化したい

Tags: javascript

HTMLに直接記述された window.location.href を JavaScript で無効化したい。

```
window.location.href = "hoge.com";
```

無効化する方法を調べたけれど分からなかったので、結果的に遷移されない方法で間接的に無効化する手段を取りました。

その方法は以下の様なScriptを実行しておくことです。

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  e.returnValue = "Block";
}
window.location.href = "hoge.com";
```

しかし実際にこのScriptを実行しても警告が出ることなくページ移動が行われました。

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  e.returnValue = "Block";
}
**>> ページ部分クリック**
window.location.href = "hoge.com";
```

けれども、この様に window.location.href を行う前にページ部分のクリックなどのイベントを挟むことで警告が出され、ページ移動は行われなくなりました。

そこで質問になります。

1. window.location.href を JavaScript で無効化する方法
2. ページクリックなどの手間を入れずにScriptだけで『このページから移動しますか？ 』という警告を表示させる方法

これのどちらか、または類する回答を頂けると幸いです。

**追記**：前提が足りないという事なので追記失礼します。

ページHTML

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <script>
      window.location.href = "hoge.com";
    </script>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

window.location.href を無効にするScriptの実行方法とタイミング

1.UserScript/拡張機能 @run-at document-start
2.コンソール (この場合はコンソール上で無効にするScriptを実行後 window.location.href を実行させます。)

Comment: 前提となっている部分が抜け落ちている印象です。このページは誰が作ったもので、挿入するスクリプトは誰がどのタイミングで挿入するものなのでしょうか？　たとえば共同でウェブページを作成している場合やブラウザの拡張機能を作ろうとしている場合など、いくつかシチュエーションが考えられ、迷っています。

Comment: 実行する（window.location.href を無効にする）Scriptは、コンソール上からでも構いませんし、UserScriptでも拡張機能でも構いません。
コンソール上で window.location.href を実行してページ移動されなければそれで良いです。

Comment: 解決していませんがこんな記事があります。[JavaScriptでプロパティ変更をインターセプトする方法](https://teratail.com/questions/22139)

Comment: UserScript と書かれていますが、もしかして Greasemonkey や Tampermonkey を使ってらっしゃいますか？（これは標準的なものではないのでもし質問の範疇に入っているなら [edit] していただきたいです。）

Comment: UserScript でも 拡張機能 でも コンソール上 でも 構わないと記載しています。とにかく JavaScript を 任意の方法で実行し  window.location.href を無効化出来れば良いです。当方の説明に問題があり、理解し難い内容になっているようでしたら、UserScript や 拡張機能 という単語は無視してくれて構いません。コンソール上で window.location.href = "hoge.com"; と実行してもページ移動されなくするScriptを教えてください。